# unable to switch back to the parent frame using selenium web driver-java?

Tags: java, selenium

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[12]/div[1]/div[5]/iframe")));

```
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlFileExtensions"))).selectByVisibleText("DLA-Extension");              
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"DLA-Extension\"]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div[1]/input[1]")).sendKeys("TestDLA");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a/input[1]")).click();      

    //Switch to new window opened
      for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
          driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
      }
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[3]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[3]/div/table[10]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[4]/a[1]/input[1]")).click();    




      driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[12]/div[1]/div[5]/iframe")));
      //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/a[1]/input[1]")).click();
      mouseClickByLocation("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/a[1]/input[1]");
```

Comment: Please try to upload compete Code which will show how you're storing the parent window handle and calling it. The code you uploaded does not covers the main part and might be the reason for Down-vote.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not as per your code. But i am showing you how you can achieve this. Just make sure you have all steps properly placed in your code.

**Step1: Store the Main window handle**

```
String Parentwindow = driver.getWindowHandle( );
```

**Step2: Click on the Link which will open the new Browser window**

**Step3: Switch to the new open browser window.**

```
for ( String currentwindow : driver.getWindowHandles())  
  driver.switchTo( ).window(currentwindow);  
       {  
       // Perform your operations on the current window    
         driver.close( )  
       }
```

**Step4: Return to the Main window**

```
driver.switchTo().window(Parentwindow);
```